# XMLHttpRequest Wrapper? (Clean up multiple requests)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm creating a script to run on a page. This page has a few ajax calls, each of them being sequential (if A works, make call B, etc).

My code:

```
function doSomething(element) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        pageCheck(this,element);

    }
}


xhr.open('GET', URL);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
}
```

Inside pageCheck, I pass element (doesn't matter what it is) and the dom object obtained through that xmlhttprequest call. Inside pageCheck I have another series of

```
pageCheck(page,item) {
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (...) {
doSomethingElse(..); 
}
xhr1.open(..)
xhr1....etc
}
```

My issue is, this looks horrible. Can't I make some wrapper for the XML requests? I had this, but realized I can't access the xhr object. How can I clean this up without fetch, jquery, promises, etc? Re-use the xhr object?

```
function XMLWrapper(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        pageCheck(this,item);

    }
}


    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();    
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Trying to clean this up I know it looks bad.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Promises will save you here. Dummy code:

```
function request (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //....
    //.... xhr setup
    //....

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      resolve(e.target.responseText)
    })

    xhr.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
      reject(new Error('some error message'));
    })

    xhr.send();
  })
}
```

Than you can:

```
request('url1')
  .then(function (data) {
    //data has the result of the first request here

    return request('url2');
  })
  .then(function (data) {
     //data has the result of the second here

   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     //if some error occurs on the way,
     //you will end up here.
   })

//and so forth
```

Please not that this is dummy code, just there to outline the way one might solve your problem with promises. A full explanation on Promises would be to much for an answer here.

Comment: Can this be done with just pure vanilla JS? Or would I have to use promises for something like this?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=promises - But there are good polyfills out there, in case you need to target browser which do not have promises.